# SteamCMD process doesn't receive input from C#

Tags: c#, process, steam

I am currently trying to make a test wrapper for SteamCMD using C#. For some reason, when I use `inStream.WriteLine()`, SteamCMD doesn't seem to receive any of the given commands. I have checked this with normal CMD and it works fine. I've tested using arguments to see if its a problem with the output but no, it should be something with the input.

```
public Form1() 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    proc = new Process {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                FileName = "steamcmd.exe",
                //Arguments = "+login anonymous",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
    };
    proc.Start();

    outStream = proc.StandardOutput;
    inStream = proc.StandardInput;

    Task.Run(() => {
            while (true) {
                textBox1Temp += outStream.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
    });
}

private Process proc;
private StreamReader outStream;
private StreamWriter inStream;

private void TestCommand_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    inStream.WriteLine("help");
}

private String? textBox1Temp;

private async void Update_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1Temp;
    Update_btn.Text = "OK";
    await PutTaskDelay(500);
    Update_btn.Text = "Update";
}
```

Comment: Looks like worth to try to add `proc.BeginOutputReadLine();` right after `proc.Start()`